# Python - Add to json list via Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7

My json file

```
{
   "people": []
}
```

My python code

```
with open("people.json") as jsonFile:
    load = json.load(jsonFile)
    data = {
    "fname": "Jason",
    "lname": "Scott",
    "age": 32,
    "job": "web developer",
    "spouse": "Jane Scott"
    }

    load["people"].append(data)

jsonFile.close()
```

I want to add to the list from my python file, with my code above, the json file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't written anything back into the file. Open up the file in write mode (`open("people.json", r+)`), then after you append the data, you'll need to `json.dump` the new dictionary into the file.

Also, no need to do `jsonFile.close()` at the end. Your `with` statement deals with that.

Comment: when dumping the data, it does not add to the list, but rather the end of the file, any idea on a fix?